# How to get group of consequence dates in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing android app in which i have to find consequence date groups.
i have followed dates in sqlite database
2013-05-04
2013-05-06
2013-05-07
2013-05-08
2013-05-10
2013-05-11
2013-05-12
2013-05-13
2013-05-14
2013-05-15
2013-05-16
2013-05-17
2013-05-26
2013-05-27

I want to group them as per following
2013-05-04
2013-05-06
2013-05-07
2013-05-08
2013-05-10
2013-05-11
2013-05-12
2013-05-13
2013-05-14
2013-05-15
2013-05-16
2013-05-17
2013-05-26
2013-05-27

So, is it possible to group these dates in sqlite ?

Comment: do you mean group them as in 'sqlite consider them equal' ?

Comment: It may be one way. if consider them equals then will it give count for each group ?

Answer (score 0):

A SQL group is not a group you think it is.

You *can* sort on a substring:

```
sqlite> select d from t order by substr(d, 0, 10);
2013-05-04
2013-05-06
2013-05-07
2013-05-08
2013-05-10
2013-05-11
2013-05-12
2013-05-13
2013-05-14
2013-05-15
2013-05-16
2013-05-17
2013-05-26
2013-05-27
```

See [the SQLite functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following query sets the value in the second column to `1` if the record is the first record in a group.
(A "first" record is any record for which no record with the previous date exists.)

```
SELECT MyDate,
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM MyTable AS T2
                   WHERE T2.MyDate = date(T1.MyDate, '-1 days')
                  ) AS FirstInGroup
FROM MyTable AS T1
ORDER BY MyDate
```

Example output:

```
2013-05-04  1
2013-05-06  1
2013-05-07  0
2013-05-08  0
2013-05-10  1
2013-05-11  0
2013-05-12  0
2013-05-13  0
2013-05-14  0
2013-05-15  0
2013-05-16  0
2013-05-17  0
2013-05-26  1
2013-05-27  0
```